# Electron JS set video source from stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to create a Desktop app using Electron JS.
The app is supposed to request a video (mp4) file using specific headers and then set the source of the video to the response I get.

My render.js file:

```
var request = require("request");

const video = document.querySelector("video");

const options = {
    url: 'http://somesite.site/resource.mp4',
    headers: {
      'Referer': 'https://somereferrer.site/'
    }
};

request(options).pipe(video.srcObject);
```

My index.html file:

```
<script defer src="render.js"></script>
<video controls></video>
```

My main.js file:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-features', 'OutOfBlinkCors');

function createWindow () {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        title: "Anime Viewer",
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            webSecurity: false
        }
    })
    win.removeMenu();
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
    win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

However, I get the following errors on the console and the video element remains the same:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
    at Request.Stream.pipe (internal/streams/legacy.js:32:8)
    at Request.pipe

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of null
    at Request.pipeDest

Uncaught Error: Parse Error: User callback error
    at Socket.socketOnData
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?